# Roles Dinamico en Symfony2

Tags: sql, symfony2, symfony3, symfony, pgadmin

Buenas tengo ese pedazo de codigo, tengo la clase "Users" y la clase "Roles", en este fragmento el metodo getRole(), perfectamente obtiene el nombre de usuario de la clase users, en este punto **return 'ROLE_' . strtoupper($this->user->getUsername());** retornando perfectamente el **ROLE_NOMBREDEUSUARIO**, pero yo quiero que me retorne el rol, entonces pongo **getRol**, y no me funciona, me retorna el id del users. En la clase Users tengo el **metodo getRol()**

Alguien podria ayudarme?

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class Roles implements RoleInterface
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getRole()
    {
        return 'ROLE_' . strtoupper($this->user->getUsername());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitarás configurar un poco más esa entidad para que funcione como creo que quieres...

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class Roles implements RoleInterface
{
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $role;

    public function __construct(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }
}
```

Por no mencionar que tu clase completa necesita configurar el mapeado del ORM a través de notaciones (si es tu caso) o en el fichero yml que hayas creado (en cuyo caso te recomiendo encarecidamente que cambies a anotaciones)